# xml format for spreadsheet

Tags: c++, xml, spreadsheet

I have a scientific c++ project, which need to report some information, like performance in each iteration, time step size in each iteration, some other specific values per iteration and total values. Definitely, it is possible to dump this information to std output, redirect to a file, that is how it works now. But it would be nice to dump this to an xml file. First it is in human readable format. Second, if this format is possible to be imported by OpenOffice, LibreOffice, that the data would be display in a nice table view with computed max, min, average and some graphics. Is there a format for that?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you asking for a the specific XML format(s) used by LibreOffice?

Comment: A [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) isn't XML, but it does satisfy your two stated requirements of being human readable **and** importable by any popular spreadsheet software.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenDocument Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) (ISO/IEC 26300:2006) and [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) (ISO/IEC 29500) are standard XML based file formats that support spreadsheets.